# How to hide a specific active app on OS Sonama (Version 14.1.1)

Tags: macos, info.plist

Is there a way to hide a running app in OS Sonama but said app won't appear in force quit or in docks.

I know there was a way in earlier OS by editing Info.plist file but that method longer works on newer OS (app crashes/doesn't launch/cant edit info.plist)

Comment: Setting LSUIElement to true in the Info.plist should still work, however Sonoma is going to want you to codesign the app.